# Why the Validation of my form in Livewire does'nt work?

Tags: forms, validation, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm doing a form on livewire as i always did it. But tonight it decides to mess with me.

I have my protected rules, and, in order to apply them, i have the "$this->validate" as you can see it on my code.

Problem is, with "$this->validate" nothing happens, no data in my table.
When i do it without "$this->validate"...it works..but of course, the rules are not applied.

Have you an idea?

`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Demande;
use Livewire\Component;

class CreateDemande extends Component
{
    public  $content, $annonce, 
            $phone, $mail, $user_id;


        

        protected $rules = [

            'content' => 'required',
    
            'user_id' => 'required',
    
        ];

    public function store()
    {
       
       
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $this->validate();
       
         Demande::create([

            'content' => $this->content,

            'user_id' => $user_id,
    
        ]);
       
          

    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-demande');
    }
}
```

`

Maybe a trait's missing ?

I tried to create a new component and doing it again, but doesn't worked too.

I tried to pass my rules in the validation :

`

```
$this->validate(

        [

            'content' => 'required',

          

            'user_id' => 'required',
    ]);
       
         Demande::create([

            'content' => $this->content,

         

            'user_id' => $user_id,
    
        ]);
```

`

Is there some error on my code i can't see here?

Edit : Sorry dont know why but the "hello" i wrote on the begining don't want to show him

Comment: What does your form look like? Why are you validating the ``user_id`` and then setting it here: ``$user_id = auth()->user()->id;``. Validate will only validate the information being sent via the inputs in your form. No need to validate a ``user_id`` if you're setting it using ``auth()->user()->id``

Comment: My form is a basic form : 
 - <form wire:submit.prevent="store">
- wire:model on every button.
For the user_id you right, i tried without it, and it didn't worked.

Comment: Since you said that without calling `->validate()` it works, my guess would be that everything works just fine, the validation runs, errors out, gives you a response, but you are not showing the validation errors on frontend. But if that is not the case, open dev tools and see what's happening in networks tab.

Comment: Oh god, you right i forgot the @errors on the front...thank you. I've worked too late this day, my brain was down.